# How can I disable my css sprite nav bars hover state for a section while it is active?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have been developing a website that makes use of a css sprite nav bar.

The css for one section which is already set as active follows.

```
ul#navigation li#navigation-1 a
{
background:url(images/btn_navbar.png) no-repeat -1px 0;
width:90px;
}

ul#navigation li#navigation-1 a.current
{
background-position:-1px -90px;
}

ul#navigation li#navigation-1 a:active,ul#navigation li#navigation-1 a:hover
{
background-position:-1px -45px;
}
```

I set the active state for the other sections using the following HTML/PHP

```
<li id="navigation-8"><a href="<?php $page = get_page_by_title('Contact'); echo get_permalink ($page ->ID); ?>" title="CONTACT" <?php if ( is_page('Contact')) { echo 'class="current"' ; } ?>><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
```

The problem is that the current 'active' section still has the :hover property which leads to a flicker and unwanted removal of the active state until the mouse leaves the section.

Ideally I would like to simply remove the hover property for the currently selected section.

How is this possible? could I do some jquery wizardry?

Many thanks.

Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the psuedo classes for the "current" link:

```
#navigation-1 a.current,
#navigation-1 a.current:hover,
#navigation-1 a.current:active {
    background-position:-1px -45px;
}
```

I also recommend you put these below the other `#navigation-1 a` styles as well, as they will override the styles they inherit from those.

I want to point out that there is no need to write a selector with 2 ids. Ids are always unique, so there's no need to even specify an element either because there will never be two of them (with **valid** html).

These are all the same (assuming your markup stays the same and you have no unused css):

```
ul#navigation li#navigation-1{}
#navigation li#navigation-1{}
#navigation-1{}
```

Comment: I just wanted to say how satisfied I am with this answer, you actually rescued me from a huge headache!

Answer (score 0):

Give the non-current links a class as well via:

```
if ( is_page('Contact'))
    { echo 'class="current"' ; }
else
    { echo 'class="notcurrent"' ;}
```

And then change your css to this:

```
ul#navigation li#navigation-1 a.notcurrent:active,
ul#navigation li#navigation-1 a.notcurrent:hover
{
    background-position:-1px -45px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I chose the alternative because of its simplicity. I appreciate your help :)